# itemsingletap on list is not detected when 1 item is tapped followed by swiftly tapping a different item?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, listener, onclicklistener

I have a list in Sencha with `itemsingletap` as listener. When I tap an item in the list, `itemsingletap` is triggered. This is the expected behavior. However, when I tap an item in the list, then swiftly tap another item in the list, `itemsingletap` is not triggered. Why is it not considered as an `itemsingletap`? How does `itemsingletap` works? I know it eliminates double tap but are there any other conditions before it can be considered as `itemsingletap`?

Thanks!

Comment: i know its old post. anyhow it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Check this its working for me.

```
config : {
            refs : {
                navigationview : 'navigationview',
                },
            control : {

                'productTable dataview[id=productDataView]':{
                    itemsingletap : 'onProductItemTap'
                }

            }
        },

            onProductItemTap: function (list, idx, target, record, evt) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('itemsingletap', record.data.Content);
     Ext.select('#resultID').elements[0].innerHTML = record.data.Content;                              
            },
```